# Programmatically create a Spring BeanFactory using annotated beans

Tags: java, spring, annotations

- I would like a BeanFactory, not an ApplicationContext
- My beans are defined via annotated Java methods (@Bean), in several classes annotated with @Configuration
- The classes live in the same package -- com.foo

Sample code:

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory bf = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();
ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner scanner = new ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(bf);
scanner.scan("com.foo");
LOGGER.info("Bean def names:");
for (String beanDefName : bf.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
    LOGGER.info("\t{}", beanDefName);
}
```

When I execute this code, it finds my @Configuration classes. However those top-level classes/beans are the only thing in the resulting BeanFactory (along with a few Spring things). It's not taking the next step to process those so the @Bean items are included as well.

For the life of me, I cannot figure out what I'm missing. I've Googled everything I can think of, but no luck (BeanFactory is too similar to FactoryBean, I think). If anyone has any suggestions/pointers, I greatly appreciate hearing them.

Comment: Why are you wanting to do that?

Comment: Startup time is important and has recently become an issue due to the sheer number of beans defined. We were using Spring 3.2.x and autowiring "by type" and Reflection seemed to be the bottleneck. This was an going to be an attempt to reduce the number of calls requiring Reflection. After getting in to it though, I went with a different approach -- autowiring "by name" and upgrading to Spring 4.2.x. For the record, I did get a bit further with this approach but I never managed to get it fully working.